# Ubuntu rvm setup issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, rvm, ubuntu-12.04

I followed this tutorial below:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin-with-rvm

This worked perfectly for me; however, I have one small problem?

Each time I open a new terminal I have to run this command in order for rails to work:

source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm

What is the problem and why is rvm not recognized

This is what I see after I open a new terminal and verify rails:

robert@rob:~$ rails -v
The program 'rails' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install rails

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I highly recommend you to use the official website to install RVM: https://rvm.io/rvm/install

---

**Your problem is** that RVM is not loaded when you open a new terminal, this is why you have to manually add the source at each instance of the Terminal.

**To solve this**, run this command line: (**if using login-shell**)

```
echo "source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Or this (**if using non-login shell**):

```
echo "source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bashrc
```

**This will** add the path to RVM to load at each Terminal instanciation (close & re-open a terminal after you did this).

---

**Take a look at @mpapis comments**

Comment: rvm should not be sourced in ~/.bashrc, it should be ~/bash_profile and login shell should be set

Comment: @mpapis updated my answer, thank you for this precision! -- Also, what if we don't use login shell? And we don't want to use it at all, ~/.bashrc is the right file to do it, no?

Comment: @mpapis Can you please answer my question in my previous comment? I would like a better explanation.

Comment: you could source rvm in ~/.bashrc - but then some unexpected and hard to debug problems happen - just avoid it, login shell is not bad thing, if you need to use rvm rubies in automation then you need wrappers and aliases not a shell configuration