# rvm command not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I installed rvm with rails, from the official website of RVM, I specified the command suggested by the tutorial.
When the installation my system has rails 4.0.0, rvm 01/23/12, ruby 2.0.0, bundler gem 1.3.5 and 2.0.3
But I need to install ruby 1.9 to practice with a course that I am currently doing. "Rails for Zombies 2"
I try to execute the instruction `rvm install 1.9.3` and the console returns this message:
`rvm: command not found`

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Possible duplicate of: [Ubuntu rvm setup issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19298814/ubuntu-rvm-setup-issue/19299320#19299320)

---

**Your problem is** that RVM is not loaded when you open a new terminal.

**To solve this**, run this command line: (**if using login-shell**)

```
echo "source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Or this (**if using non-login shell**):

```
echo "source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bashrc
```

Or if you are using `zsh` (and/or oh-my-zsh):

```
echo "source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.zshrc
```

This will add the path to RVM to load at each Terminal instantiation. You must either close and reopen your terminals or simply call `source ~/.bashrc` (or `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.zshrc`).

Comment: thank you very much for the quick response.
Sorry to say that the problem has not been solved, but thanks.
We'll see. I've opened `bash_profile` file to verify that it has written the line, and effectively written.
After I closed and re-open the terminal.
When I write `rvm-v` terminal returns the   version o f me but if I write   `rvm install 1.9.3`
the same mistake again

Comment: when I include the line you suggest, the terminal returns me the following error:
`-bash: / home / <user> / .rvm / scripts / rvm: No such file or directory`

Comment: Just make sure that you don't have "sh" as your default shell because rvm won't load on such a simple shells without warning

Comment: added source ~/.bash_profile then it works for me after above command to update on system

Comment: If you followed the official instructions to install [rvm](https://github.com/rvm/ubuntu_rvm), you can also add `source "/etc/profile.d/rvm.sh"` to your bashrc.

Comment: When you want to use `~/. bash_profile` you need to `source` it with the command `source ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: For Debian 11:  `echo "source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bashrc`

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem after installing zsh. I'm a domain user so my $PATH and $HOME are not as straight-forward. What worked for me was

`echo "source /usr/share/rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.zshrc`

Comment: great answer it works thanks

Answer (score 0):

The latest installation needs the users to be added to the Group `rvm` and then need to login again.

Please note that closing the terminal and reopening is not enough; the user has to logout and log back to take the Group addition in effect.

Adding the user to the Group can be done by:

```
sudo usermod -a -G rvm <user>
```

The binaries can also be at different locations based on the method you followed during the installation.
I had them at `/usr/share/rvm/`

You can also look at `/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm`

Then you add this line to the end of `~/.bashrc`

```
[[ -s /usr/share/rvm/scripts/rvm ]] && source /usr/share/rvm/scripts/rvm
```

**Note:** If you are using a shell other than `bash` you may need to add the path accordingly.

For instance, if you using `zsh` shell add the above lines to the `~/.zshrc` file.

Answer (score 0):

some steps to follow:

Prerequisites: Homebrew (should be pre-installed )

1. brew install gnupg
2. Install GPG keys (there is 2 way to install given below, pick any one)

first-way ==>$  gpg --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB

second-way ==> $ gpg --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB

3. install RVM

run: $ \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash

We will receive a thank you  message in the console. Quit all Terminal and Launch a new Terminal.

4. $ rvm list

we will get this message (# No rvm rubies installed yet. Try 'rvm help install'.)

5. $ rvm install 2.7.1 (choose any you want to install)
6. $ rvm list

   you will find which ruby version currently you are using need to change here as default.

7.$ rvm alias create default 2.7.1

now your version will be set. Enjoy