# RVM not working on Vagrant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ubuntu, rvm, vagrant

No command 'rvm' found, but there are 21 similar ones rvm: command not found. Comes up when I'm in Vagrant on linux ubuntu 14.04.

Installed Vagrant and VirtualBox.

Answer (score 1):

Found over at [rvm command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19595974/rvm-command-not-found)

---

**Your problem is** that RVM is not loaded when you open a new terminal.

**To solve this**, run this command line: (**if using login-shell**)

```
echo "source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Or this (**if using non-login shell**):

```
echo "source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bashrc
```

This will add the path to RVM to load at each Terminal instanciation (close & re-open a terminal after you did this).

---

You could also try, if you're sshd into your box, running sudo apt-get update and then installing it?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well. I found that I had to add the full path for `rvm` in the provisioning script. The path is added to the environmental $PATH variable but not known to Vagrant during the provisioning.

```
/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm install ruby-2.4.0
```

After provisioning:

```
[vagrant@Ruby ~]$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin: \
/usr/local/rvm/bin:/home/vagrant/.local/bin:/home/vagrant/bin

[vagrant@Ruby ~]$ which rvm
/usr/local/rvm/bin/rvm
```

Another option might be to `source /etc/profile` before executing an `rvm`, but I have not tried that yet.